# Gödel's proof method and fundamental theorem of arithmetic

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I am a novice to Gödel's proof (the theorem that consistency contradicts completeness), and, as it seems to me, he uses the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to uniquely number any formula.

My question is: It seems like the proof is circular?

Comment: Why would that be circular? He used one theorem to prove another theorem.

Comment: Can you be more precise in your objection ? In G's Incompleteness Th the *consistency* of arithmetic is assumed. Thus, using a theorem of arithemtic in the proof, G is not guilty of circularity, because he does **not** aim to prove he consistency of arithemtic, but a different fact.

Comment: The incompleteness theorem not only assumes the theory being studied is complete, it also assumes the theory being studied is *sufficiently strong*. This includes being strong enough to prove things like the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. Of course, we can give a precise description of a theory that is strong enough, and PA satisfies that description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\sf PA$ proves the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (the usual proof goes through just fine), then $\sf PA$ proves that the encoding is unique.

It is important to note that the function mapping a formula to its number is *not* internal to the model of $\sf PA$, a model of $\sf PA$ is not aware of the syntax which lives in "a different place". What happens is that we define a set of codes and some rules, and we prove that these codes and rules are, internally, similar to those of the language and logic, so we can talk about formula as if they were integers.

The key part is to show that the set of these codes (or at least the sets of relevant codes) are recursive, or recursively enumerable (and not recursive).

Comment: Hey thanks so much, from your information I may get some ''feeling'' about the issue. But I figure that to totally understand the point is not immediately reachable.

Comment: Total understanding comes only after studying the subject for a while, and preferably teaching it to someone else at least twice. That's how I gained my understanding (quite recently too, this year was my second year TA'ing the logic course in which this theorem is proved).